# jQuery Navigation tab add class when hovered

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I am working on a navigation dropdown menu with jQuery. The navigation menu show the sub tabs when you hover the parent tab. But I want to add a class to the parent tab when it's hovered So I can give this the same color as the sub tabs when hovered.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

My jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li").hover(function() {
            $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li a", this).addClass('hover');
            $("ul.sub-menu", this).slideToggle(50);
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-header-container">
    <ul id="menu-header" class="menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.url.com/">Risicomanagement</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://www.url.com/">Bedrijfsaansprakelijkheidsverzekering</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32"><a href="http://www.url.com/">Beroepsaansprakelijkheidsverzekering</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://www.url.com/">Bestuurdersaansprakelijkheidsverzekering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://www.url.com/">Pensioen</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="http://www.url.com/">Hypotheek</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="http://www.url.com/">Zorg</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://www.url.com/">Consultancy</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you need it for? If only for CSS, have you considered using CSS `:hover` selectors?

Comment: Yes but when I hover first my parent tab and then my childs than the hover state goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("a").addClass('hover');
        $(this).closest(".sub-menu").slideToggle(50);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83Ujj/ CSS: added in jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#menu-header li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find("a").addClass("hover");
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find("a").removeClass("hover");
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').hide();
    });
});
```